# Jenkins run ANT exec on screen (visibly)

Tags: ant, jenkins

I have a build.xml file with the following line at the end:

```
<ant dir="${basedir}/subfolder" target="mytarget" />
```

Then in the subfolder, I have another build.xml file with the following:

```
<target name="mytarget">
    <exec executable="open">
        <arg value="${basedir}/myApp.app" />
    </exec>
</target>
```

The `myApp.app` application is designed to be executed visibly on the screen, and not in the background.  It is an app designed in Automator and it has mouse movement and clicking incorporated.  I set up Jenkins to build this task on a slave, and when the task is built I want Jenkins to call the ant script which will launch this application, and then I want the application to actually cause the mouse to move around on the Jenkins slave.  Right now Jenkins reports a successful build, but nothing seems to be happening.

**UPDATE**

When I run the exec with `failonerror="true"`, no error prints to the Jenkins log.  Jenkins just says **mytarget:** as though it is about to start printing the log info for that target, and then nothing happens and the build completes successfully, with nothing happening on the slave (the app is not launched).

**UPDATE 2**

I just had an interesting find.  I replaced the line `${basedir}/myApp.app` with `/Applications/Dictionary.app`, and when I ran that with Jenkins it opened up the dictionary for a tiny second and then closed it immediately.  Could that be happening with my application too without anything showing up?  My script has a delay in the beginning, so could it be closing during that period?

Comment: The `<exec>` task has `failonerror` set to `false` by default. If you set this parameter to `true`, the app will fail the build if it can't execute. That might give you more information. I suspect that the slave process does not have permission to run on the screen.

Comment: When I am logged in as the slave user on the slave machine I can execute it fine.  I'll let you know what happens with failonerror.

Comment: What system is this on? How are you launching this slave?

Comment: The slave is a mac mini.  I am listening for changes on GitHub, then when the build runs the updated code is pulled into the workspace on the slave, and then the ant script which is in that pulled code gets run.  Then the build finishes successfully.

Comment: How are you launching this slave? Via ssh? Webstart? Have you tried starting some other GUI application through Jenkins?

Comment: via SSH.  I have not tried any other GUI application - is there a way to actually make a terminal window show up on the slave or something like that?

Comment: Slave launched from ssh usually do not have access to desktop. Try launching it via webstart. I'm not exactly sure how it will work on mac. On linux you can create virtual desktop vith Xvnc.

Comment: when I ssh into the slave machine and run the ant task, it works fine.  So I don't think this is an ssh issue.  Also I don't want to use webstart, but ssh should work, just not sure what's wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `open` command is just launching the application but doesn't care of its lifecycle. It is launching the application and give back the running thread to Ant. Ant is then terminating the `exec` task, so the target, so the build, so Ant itself.

I think the solution is to add the `-W` option to `open` so it "waits until the applications it opens (or that were already open) have exited".

```
<exec executable="open">
    <arg value="-W" />
    <arg value="${basedir}/myApp.app" />
</exec>
```

Comment: I will try this, thank you!  Right now Jenkins does just exit so it worked by putting a sleep on Jenkins, and I was actually just about to put that answer here when I got your response.  Since your response is also related to wait time this is definitely hitting on the issue - I will test the -W and let you know!